# Deleting last characters of a file

Tags: php, file

```
<?php
$file="datenbank.data";
$suffix = ")\n?>";      //schließt Array, und schließt php
echo "FINE.<br>";
function schreibeDatei(){
    global $file;
    file_put_contents($file, var_export($_GET, true).",\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
function öffneDatei(){
     global $file;
    file_put_contents($file, ")\n?>", FILE_APPEND);
    include ($file);
    global $db;
    print_r($db);
    }
schreibeDatei();
öffneDatei();
?>
```

hey there, with this i want to save arrays to a file in an array.
the file is prepared looks like this:

```
<?php
$db=array(
```

now running the `schreibeDatei()` function, it looks e.g. like this:

```
<?php
$db=array(array (
  'name' => 'foo',
  'passwort' => 'bar',
),
```

now running `öffneDatei()` will append this:

```
)?>
```

this is fine to include the array, but now i want to append new data to the array with `schreibeDatei()`...
how can i do this?

I think of sth like deleting the last few characters...

Comment: Would you mind switching to `serialize()` and `unserialize()`? Writing and reading would be extremely easy with them.

Comment: I just don´t know how to use them, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034184/deleting-last-characters-of-a-file/20034460#comment29835953_20034184):

```
function loadDB($file) {
  return unserialize( file_get_contents($file) );
}

function saveDB($file, $data) {
  return file_put_contents($file, serialize($data));
}

$db = loadDB('test.txt');
// do something with $db
// for example add an entry: $db['test'] = 'Hallo, Hello, Hola!';

// save to file
saveDB('test.txt', $db);
```

Comment: hmmm... i get an error:
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 123 bytes in *document* on line 3
Line 3: $db=unserialize( file_get_contents($file) );

Comment: @m00lti You probably have your old content in the file. Try saving some initial data first before loading it (for example call `saveDB('test.txt', array('name' => 'test', 'password' => 'test'));`).

Comment: ah ok... sry for that mistake:
but one more question: 
to save i need FILE_APPEND?
`file_put_contents($file,serialize($_GET), FILE_APPEND);`
now i unserialize:
`$db=unserialize( file_get_contents($file) );`
`print_r($db);`
output: just one array, i inserted 2

Comment: @m00lti No, you don't need `FILE_APPEND`. You now load the whole array from the file and also save the whole array into the file (no appending, that's a complete rewrite).